# CryptoJS and Google's Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, cryptojs

I'm writing a library and was trying to use Closure Compiler's advanced optimization features to minify my code further.

The library's built with TypeScript and I'm using Google's CryptoJS and am compiling with `--allowJS`. I've written externs for the methods I'm wanting to expose; but when I am getting errors that are coming from CryptoJS's [core library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core.js). From what it looks like; it seems annotated for Closure Compiler so I'm confused why it's breaking.
I'm taking advantage of the source maps provided by closure compiler so I can inspect the minified code.

Specifically on line 495; `this._data.concat(data);`. Claims `this._data` is undefined when minifed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that while CryptoJS has JSDoc annotations, it wasn't written for compatibility with Closure-Compiler advanced optimizations. I can tell because it's JSDoc annotations for optional parameters are not correct.

You would most likely want to use CryptoJS as an external library.